# How to restore the normal height of my navigation when it is fixed (sticky navigation)?

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

everyone, So, I'm posting this thread, because I need help about my sticky navigation for my website. I coded my simple jQuery code to achieve that, but I need help please. When my page is scrolled and that the browser affects my navigation: http://prntscr.com/9rnuqy I add a fixed class to the navigation and it is fixed to the top of my page. Problem: when my navigation is fixed, the height is not normal.

When my navigation is not fixed: http://prntscr.com/9rnvg1 (we can still see my page title)

When my navigation is fixed: http://prntscr.com/9rnw19

I know that when a navigation is fixed, we need to add a padding-top (to the body) having the same pixels as the height of the element you want to set.

HTML code for my navigation:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="navigation">
        <span id="menu-trigger" title="Navigation"></span>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>
                <a href="." class="home <?php if($body_id == "home"): ?>active<?php endif; ?>">Accueil</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="users.php" class="users <?php if($body_id == "users"): ?>active<?php endif; ?>">Utilisateurs</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="downloads <?php if($body_id == "downloads"): ?>active<?php endif; ?>">Téléchargements</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="about-us <?php if($body_id == "about-us"): ?>active<?php endif; ?>">À propos de nous</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Header */

#header
{
    background-color: #3C5E79;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 170px;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}

#logo
{
    width: 300px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: normal;
}

#logo a
{
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#logo p
{
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

/* Navigation */

#navigation
{
    background-color: #30475A;
    height: 55px;
}

/* sticky navigation */

#navigation.fixed
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#navigation.wrapper
{
    padding: 0;
}

#menu-trigger
{
    display: none;
}

#navigation li
{
    float: left;
}

#navigation a
{

    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 55px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

#navigation a:hover,
#navigation .active
{
    color: #FFF;
}

#navigation .active
{
    background-color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function()
{
    /* STICKY NAVIGATION */
    $(window).scroll(function()
    {
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= 170)
        {
            $("#navigation").addClass("wrapper fixed");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#navigation").removeClass("wrapper fixed");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: title question confused me. did you know about sticky position : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position & a polyfill http://philipwalton.github.io/polyfill/demos/position-sticky/  a basic example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLePPG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

jQuery

```
$(function()
{
    /* STICKY NAVIGATION */
    $(window).scroll(function()
    {
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= 170)
        {
            $("#navigation").addClass("wrapper fixed");
            $("body").addClass("fixed-body");

        }
        else
        {
            $("#navigation").removeClass("wrapper fixed");
            $("body").removeClass("fixed-body");
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
body.fixed-body{
padding-top: 80px;
}
```

Note: If on the body not work, should be on the right container.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to add a class to the body when a scroll is detected, not on the navigation.

Then add css rules :

```
body.navigation-fixed  {
  padding-top: 50px; // i don't know the real value
}

body.navigation-fixed #navigation {
  position: fixed;
}
```